# How to aggregate two collections from MongoDB using Express?

Tags: mongodb, express, mern

So I currently have two collections. One that is 'posts' and the other one that is 'users'

This is post:

- _id
- title
- text
- user
- date

and this is users:

- _id
- username
- email
- password

I'm trying to use aggregate in the following way:

```
router.get('/:user_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // const profile = await User.findById(req.params.user_id);
    const profile = await User.agregate([
      {
        '$lookup': {
          'from': 'posts',
          'localField': '_id',
          'foreignField': 'user',
          'as': 'posts'
        }
      }
    ]);

    // Verify profile exists
    if (!profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });

    res.json(profile);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if (err.kind == 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});
```

Notice that the first profile constant is commented but that's the one I use to fetch the users data according to the _id(**req.params.user_id**) of X user.

Now what I would like to create is to display all of the posts created by X user by accessing to their profile, so I need to match the corresponding user, I need to pass the **req.params.user_id**.

This is the new code that I have which is not working:

```
router.get('/:user_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // const profile = await User.findById(req.params.user_id);
    const profile = await User.agregate([
      {
        '$lookup': {
          'from': 'posts',
          'localField': '_id',
          'foreignField': 'user',
          'as': 'posts'
        }
      }, {
        $unwind: "$posts"
      }, {
        $match: {
          "posts.user": req.params.user_id
        }
      }
    ]);

    // Verify profile exists
    if (!profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });

    res.json(profile);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if (err.kind == 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});
```

The error that is displayed in my console.log is 'user.aggregate is not a function'. Hopefully I could explain myself, thanks!.

I just want to add a new field(posts array) into the the users collection.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has come to the same requirement just as I did, here it is the solution after two days of researching and asking lol.

```
router.get('/:user_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.user_id;
    const [profile, postsByUser] = await Promise.all([User.findById(userId, '-password'), Post.find({ user: userId }).populate('user', ['_id', 'username', 'avatar']).sort({ date: -1 })]);

    // Verify profile exists
    if (!profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });

    // res.json(profile);
    res.json({ ...profile.toJSON(), postsByUser });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if (err.kind == 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even nowadays that's a useful example. Except the typo:

```
const profile = await User.agregate([
```

should be

```
const profile = await User.aggregate([
```